# jQuery - Apply CSS to matched items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a html layout that looks like this..

```
<div class="container>

    <div class="panel">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <img class="match" src="myimage.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel">
       <div>
            <div class="item">
                <div class="img_container">
                    <img class="match">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I am trying to modify it so that it looks like this..

```
<div class="container style="align-items: stretch;">

    <div class="panel">
        <div>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <img class="match" src="myimage.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel">
       <div style="height: 100%;">
            <div class="item style="height:  100%;">
                <div class="img_container" style="height:  100%;">
                    <img class="match" src="myimage.jpg">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have looked into CSS selectors but I don't think they will work for me in this instance.

How can I do this using jQuery?  I would like it to detect if the container class exists and then apply the CSS to the items.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to use jQuery for this? CSS would make much more sense.

Comment: I need to only run this if the image class 'match' is found.  I need to work backwards through the selectors which is why I didn't think CSS would work in this instance

Answer (score 1):

I guess something like this. Please try it out whether it's working

```
// if el with container class exists will add align-item css
// $('.container').css('align-items','stretch');
// updated, will only apply 'align-items' on container which contains img with class 'match'
$('img.match').closest('.container').css('align-items','stretch');

// assign div with item class, its div parent, and img_container class with height:100%
$('.item').css('height','100%');
$('.img_container').css('height','100%');
$('.item').closest('div').css('height','100%');

// get the src of the first img el with class "match" and assign it to the 2nd img el with class "match"
var src = $('.match').first().attr('src');
if(src){ 
    $('.match').last().attr('src',src);
}
```

Comment: That works great, thank you!  Is there a way to only apply align-item stretch to the .container that has the images inside with the match class? i have several other .containers which I don't want the CSS to be applied to

Comment: @fightstarr20 yes sure, please find the edited answer per your request. If you only want to run this script block only for the `container` class which contains img with class `match`, you'll need to store the `$('img.match').closest('.container')` in a variable and do all your jQuery search from this container only.

Comment: @fightstarr20 does it help with your issue? Feel free to ask us any more question. If this answer help to solve your issue, please consider to matk it as accepted. Thanks!